# Object-fit does not cover the entire containing area

Tags: css, object-fit

The image does not cover the containing area completely (you can see that little teal strip at the bottom.)

Why is that? and what can I do in so that the image can cover the div completely?

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: teal;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://icatcare.org/app/uploads/2018/07/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add display: block; to your image.

```
img{
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block;
}
```

As an **alternative**, you can add font-size: 0px; to your .container class.

The issue is not with Object-fit rule, the issue is with display: inline-block rule which adds unnecessary whitespace to HTML. The way to fix it is to either convert the element to display: block, or to give the parent of the element font-size: 0px, so the whitespace 'takes no space'.

You can read a bit more about it here:

https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block